# How to update notification without affecting the pending intent and its payload?

Tags: android, android-pendingintent

I am creating a notification using the below code:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, GetStockQuote.class);
            intent.putExtra("abc", abcObject);
            intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            PendingIntent pIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent, 0);

            /* Build the notification */
            Notification notification = new Notification.Builder(this)
                                     .setContentTitle(abcObject.getCode())
                                     .setContentText(abcObject.getText())
                                     .setAutoCancel(false)
                                     .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
                                     .setContentIntent(pIntent).build();
 NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
            notificationManager.notify(notificationID,notification);
            Log.i(TAG,"notification.notified");
```

As you can see the `PendingIntent` attached to the notification carries a payload. It's an object of a custom class.

Now I update the notification in a service. I understand that if you have to update a notification (without creating a new one), you have to specify the same `notificationID` which I am doing.

This is the code in the service used to update the notification that was created above:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, GetStockQuote.class);
                PendingIntent pIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent, 0);   
 Notification notification=new Notification.Builder(this)
                                .setContentTitle(newTitle)
                                .setContentText(newBody)
                                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
                                .setContentIntent(pIntent)
                                .build();

                /*Get instance of Notification Manager and show the notification*/
                        NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
                        notificationManager.notify(notificationID,notification);
```

The code updates the existing notification with the new content, but the `PendingIntent` does not contain the payload.

I don't have access to the payload in the service. So, I would like to just update the notification service with it's new `textContent` without affecting the payload that was set during this creation.

Now the problem is I have many such notifications. Each of them has a unique payload but the destination class in the `Intent` remains the same.

Is there a way to retain the payload when updating a notification?

Comment: When you start a service you can pas your object to the service so you can access it in service.

Comment: @MisaghEmamverdi nope, that is not possible. The service is started once and it updates whatever notifications are active.

Comment: You mean the service should pass different extra objects to pending intent?

Comment: @MisaghEmamverdi The service runs every 15 minutes. And when it runs, it updates whatever notifications are active.

Comment: So when service runs if for example 5 notifications are active, it will update them and pass 5 different objects to them. Am I correct?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are setting your pending intent with same id for all notifications.

use this

```
PendingIntent pIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, notificationID, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
```

instead of

```
PendingIntent pIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent, 0);
```

Comment: yeah man. It worked. So what is the use of this second parameter exactly - requestCode? There is not much given in Android Developer Docs

Answer (score 0):

However I am not sure it is the only way or the best way it may help you:

First define parser methods for your class that should be passed to intent. You need this 2 methods:

```
public static String getStringObject(YourObj obj) // return your fileds as string
public static YourObj parse(String input) // parse the string and create an object
```

Then each time you want to show a new notification add this:

```
SharedPreferences sp = getSharedPreferences("pref",MODE_PRIVATE);
Set<String> notifications = sp.getStringSet("nots", null);
if(notifications==null){
    notifications = new HashSet<String>();
}
notifications.add(id + "|" + YourObject.getStringObject(abcObject));
sp.edit().putStringSet("nots", notifications).commit();
```

In your service you will access to your object by calling (for example first active notification):

```
YourObj obj = YourObj.parse(new ArrayList<String>(sp.getStringSet("nots", null)).get(0).split("|")[1]);
// I didn't check if list is null. You should do it
```

You must update this active list and remove removed notifications from list. You can use this by setting `setDeleteIntent` for notification.